# array for Fixed rate

Tags: java

i have to find Population for pond . it has starting population when user input n after that use input Fixed rate for the population finally user input for how many gerbartion to calculate the current population . Im stuck at array of calculation how write the code it .can someone help me.Thax

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class population {

    private static final int TARGET = 6000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iStartingPopulation,iFGeneration,iRate;

        int[] iGrowthRate = new int[10];



        Scanner inConsole = new Scanner (System.in);

        //  Read the starting population of the fish pond
        System.out.println(" Enter the starting population of the Fish pond");
        iStartingPopulation= inConsole.nextInt();

    // Ask whether the growth rate is fixed or variable  
        System.out.println(" Enter F for fixed growth rate of the pond, V for Variable ");
        char option = inConsole.next().charAt(0);

        if ( option ==('f') || option==('F')){

        //Read the fixed Growth Rate 
        System.out.println("Enter the fixed growth rate for genration:");
        iRate = inConsole.nextInt();

        //Read the fixed Growth for how many Generation 
        System.out.println("Enter How many Generation for:");
         iFGeneration= inConsole.nextInt(); 



int iFCurrentPopulation= iStartingPopulation;


        for (int iI =0; iI < iFiGeneration; iI++)
        {
            iFCurrentPopulation = iFGeneration+( iFCurrentPopulation *iRate /100);
            System.out.println("Population :" +""+iFCurrentPopulation);
```

Comment: What is 'gerbartion'?

Comment: maybe he means 'generation'?

Comment: Hmm possibly. I am struggling to understand what exactly the OP wants here.

Comment: sorry my fault . like user wants to put for any generation as he wants. for example user give starting population afterwards user gives a fixed rate. Finally user give for how many generation . the result want for the current population afterwards.. .

Comment: example:- user gives starting population is 100 , user give fixed rate 80% , user give fixed rate for 5 generation. result 1st generation 100+ (100*80/100) 2nd generation 180+ (180*80/100) 3rd Generation 324+(324*80/100) ...... like any for any generation as user like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have the solution in your comment; you even have the extra variable required to keep the `population` as is when dividing in your formula.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iFGeneration; i++) {
    iFCurrentPopulation += ((iFCurrentPopulation * iRate) / iStartingPopulation);
}
```

**Note:** this will produce an `int` (obviously) as the result - where as if you want decimal places etc, you should use a `double`.

*Example:*

> Initial population = 100
>
> Fixed Rate = 80
>
> Generation = 3

Will produce `583` (as an `int`), but in reality the figure would be `583.2` (as a `double`).

[See it online!](https://ideone.com/SVBds9)

Comment: you cant divide it from starting population in here . above its work coz you give 100 for istarting population however you method is right . i only had to change istarting population  in to 100 . i entered different inputs and checks n its work. Thank you so much!!